# How to Freeze table header in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I want to Freeze the table header in Splunk and also want to add vertical scrolling in the table. Let me know if there is a way to achieve this in Splunk.

TIA !!

Comment: How is the table header broken?  Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: @RichG fixed :p

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about the dashboard table header, since normal search results natively have table header docked to the top of the scree, Please look through [this](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Fix-table-header-and-add-vertical-scrollbar-using-CSS-and/td-p/300908) post in Splunk community. Solution from *Vnravikumar* does what you need. Didn't find anything better